# PHP cannot run Python function subprocess

Tags: php, python

I've a good python script that can run on command line (it use some external program in subprocess call). But the problem is that when I try to run it from PHP by system("python test.py") it seems stuck at this line:
    warp is simple command line example
    "gdalwarp input.hdf output.tif"

```
**output = subprocess.check_output(warp, shell=True);**
```

Please note that I can run it from python script but cannot run from PHP script (it seems cannot run **subporcess** and **os.path.exists**

Thanks